# Need a way to obtain total instances after finding using FINDSTR

Tags: batch-file, findstr

So this is what I have so far and it works finding the specified string but I need it to echo the total number of times it's found.

```
FINDSTR /C:"\"MA\"" %FN%
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`findstr` has no counter, but `find` has (but has no regex).

Also `findstr /c:` searches for `\"MA\"` literally. You should add `/R` (assuming you search for `"MA"`). 
You can combine both commands to your needs:

```
FINDSTR /R /C:"\"MA\"" %FN% | find /c /v ""
```

Comment: I need it to find "MA" with quotes and echo number of instances.

Comment: I'm a dummy. Figured it out. Thanks for the help.

Comment: keep in mind: that's not exactly "number of occurences", but "number of lines, which contain" - which may or may not make a difference for you.